# PHP add and merge sql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql result:

Username Size

- John 10
- John 20
- John 30
- Jane 6
- Jane 44
- Jane 10

but I need this:

- John 60
- Jane 60

How can I merge the SQL results with PHP?

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["user_id"], " " , $row["size"], "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You want to sum the min and max of each name? Are those on separated columns or same columns?

Comment: Way too little information provided for any useful answers. What is your table schema? What is you php code? Did you even try anything yourself? What code would that have been?

Comment: I want to sum each value for each unique  user. user and size are seperated columns.

Comment: If you want this, then your example is clearly wrong since John's sum would be 60. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You should use SQL to handle the addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you wish to create a new array with the name and size combined. Here is an example:

```
$combined = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!isset($combined[ $row["user_id"] ])) { $combined[ $row["user_id"] ] = 0; }
    $combined[ $row["user_id"] ] += $row["size"];
}
foreach($combined as $userid => $size) {
    echo $userid ." ". $size ."<br>";
}
```

First you loop, and combine by same-id. Then you loop to display the results.